# fancyhdr with biblatex printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, fancyhdr

I have a problem with using `fancyhdr` package. I have made a heading that works fine, but in the Chapter References the heading looks different. How can I make that they all look the same?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11 pt, liststotoc, bibtotoc, bibtotocnumbered, liststotocnumbered ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}          
\geometry{top=4cm , bottom=4cm}
%\geometry{width=15cm, left=3.5cm, top=3cm , bottom=4cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}[babel]
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{fontenc}[T1]

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}

\section{Einleitung}
hello \cite{mi}
\subsection{first chapter}

\newpage

\printbibliography[title=Referenzen]

\newpage
\end{document}
```

Bibliography `literatur.bib`

```
@article{mi,
    author = {mira},
    title = {cgc},
    journaltitle = {journaltitle},
    date = {2020},
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but `\usepackage{ngerman}[babel]` should be `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your document, you should see a warning like the following in the `.log` file

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use 
(scrartcl)              package `scrlayer' or `scrlayer-scrpage', because
(scrartcl)              they support KOMA-Script classes.
(scrartcl)              With `fancyhdr' several features of class `scrartcl'
(scrartcl)              like options `headsepline', `footsepline' or command
(scrartcl)              `\MakeMarkcase' and the commands `\setkomafont' and
(scrartcl)              `\addtokomafont' for the page style elements need
(scrartcl)              explicite user intervention to work.
(scrartcl)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 19.
```

As the warning explains, `fancyhdr` does not work particularly well with `scrartcl`. One of the issues that can arise if you use these two together is that the column headers may not always look uniform (depending on whether or not `fancyhdr` or `scrartcl` retained control over the header).

I'd follow the recommendation in the warning and would drop `fancyhdr` in favour of `scrlayer-scrpage` if you use a KOMA-Script class.

The following should give you output very similar to what you get at the moment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, listof=numbered, bibliography=numbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=4cm , bottom=4cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{fontenc}[T1]
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[automark, headsepline, markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ohead*{\rightmark}
\chead*{}
\cefoot*{\thepage}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\section{Einleitung}
hello \cite{sigfridsson}
\subsection{first chapter}

\clearpage

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of first page of bibliography with all caps header.]

---

If you must stick with `fancyhdr` you can try to redefine `\MakeMarkcase`. This worked in the example, but additional work may be required in larger documents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, listof=numbered, bibliography=numbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=4cm , bottom=4cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{fontenc}[T1]
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\MakeMarkcase{\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}

\section{Einleitung}
hello \cite{sigfridsson}
\subsection{first chapter}

\clearpage

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey :)Thank you very much! I used the second option with fancyhdr, which works great. With scrlayer I got an new problem, because I do not like to have the heading on the first chapters and in the list of tables. With fancyhdr I put the \pagestyle{fancy} right where I want the headings to start. Anyways problem solved! :)

Comment: @MiraDürr In that case you may want to look into using a report or book-like class `scrreprt` or `scrbook`. With those classes there is a `\chapter` command. The first pages of a chapter usually get a different style. That might make things a bit easier. Anyway, if the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it to show that the problem is resolved, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers